# How can I open list of urls in one window?

Tags: javascript

I want to know how I can open a series of urls in one tab.  I have a list of urls, and I just want to open each one so its contents will be cached, just using one open tab so I don't end up with dozens of open tabs.

Comment: The answer is generally "no", you can't open multiple url's in the same tab, but if you show us what sort of files you want to open, there are ways to precache images and other resources etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use ** iframes ** one for each URL.

They can be made borderless using CSS if desired.

Answer (score 0):

This is the my solution for your problem:

**Html**

```
<button onclick="changeURL()">
  Change URL
</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
var listOfURL = ["https://www.google.es",
  "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
  "https://www.youtube.com"
];
var indexURL = 0;
var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");

function changeIndexURL() {
  indexURL += 1;
  if (indexURL >= listOfURL.length) {
    indexURL = 0;
  }
}

function changeURL() {
  iframe.setAttribute("src", listOfURL[indexURL]);
  iframe.style.width = 640 + "px";
  iframe.style.height = 480 + "px";
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  changeIndexURL();
}

changeURL();
```

Comment: Thanks Aral, almost perfect. Instead of opening as iframes, could it open a url, pause, then open another in the same window like a slideshow?

Comment: Ah ok! I edited now with your requirements! I hope now helps you! :)

Comment: Thanks Aral, but I only get one url with that, there is no child frame appearing...